# Capture email address from an email send and send the email to a Cloud Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, email, cloudpage

I have an email from email studio go to a group of contacts. The name of the data extension is called "SmartCapture". On the email, when a person clicks the submit button, he or she will then be taken to a cloud page.

I'm wanting to capture the person's email from the email after the button is clicked and then pre-populate the email address field with what was pulled from the button click.

So the process would look like this:
Email received -> take survey button clicked on the email -> email address captured -> person lands on cloud page where they see their email already on the landing page.

So far I have the following built but it is not working. May I have help with where I am going wrong?

Below is stored on the email:

```
%%[
    Var @link
    Set @link = Concat('https://fe3715717564047b731274.pub.s11.sfmc-content.com/uujkvwp3qzv/emailaddr=', AttributeValue('emailaddr'))
]%%

<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@https://fe3715717564047b731274.pub.s11.sfmc-content.com/uujkvwp3qzv)=%%">CTA Button</a>
```

Stored on the cloud page:

```
var queryString = window.location.search;
var params = new URLSearchParams(queryString.substring(1)); // drops the leading "?"
var username = parseInt(params.get('emailaddr'));
```

Comment: Your  link  should look something like this <a href = "%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%">CTA Button</a>

Comment: Thanks @SwatiMishra. The url is now showing the person's email, which is great. However, the script is not pulling the email into the email field. May I have your opinion on the below. Is there something I'm missing? var queryString = window.location.search;
var params = new URLSearchParams(queryString.substring(1)); // drops the leading "?"
var emailaddr = parseInt(params.get('emailaddr'));

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your setting a `@link` variable and then not using it. In the actual button, you should be redirecting to `@link`, not `@http://...` that’s why it seems that the button is working fine, but it’s actually not. This should fix it:

```
%%[
    Var @link
    Set @link = Concat('https://fe3715717564047b731274.pub.s11.sfmc-content.com/uujkvwp3qzv/emailaddr=', AttributeValue('emailaddr'))
]%%

<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%">CTA Button</a>
```

Since you’re redirecting the subscriber to a Cloud Page, there’s an easier way to do this by uisng the CloudPagesURL function, which will pass a bunch of parameters automatically.

In the email, use:

```
<a href="%%=CloudPagesURL(123)=%%">CTA Button</a>
```

Replace 123 with the Id of the Cloud Page, which can be found in the Properties of the Cloud Page.

Now on the CloudPage you can do the following:

```
<script runat=server>
     var contactEmail = Platform.Variable.GetAttributeValue('EmailAddr');
</script>
```

Or you can use AMPscript which would be even more straight forward:

```
%%[
set @emailaddr = emailaddr
]%%
```

And display this as a form field value:

```
<input ... value="%%=v(@emailaddr)=%%”>
```

Documentation and links:

CloudPagesURL: https://ampscript.guide/cloudpagesurl/
SSJS GetAttributeValue: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformFieldAttributeGetAttributeValue.htm
Creating forms on CloudPages with AMPscript: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/09/22/create-a-sales-service-cloud-integrated-lead-capture-form-using-ampscript/